# How do you Save calculated columns from one table to another table using Oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

As the question states, I'm trying to save calculated data, that is the result of a select statement, to another table. [In this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ1Ej.jpg), the column with green outline is a database column and the columns with red outline are calculated based on that column, I want to save the Red outlined columns to another table where the column names would be same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a classic report. Is it? If so, it is result of a `select` statement. As it calculates all values you're interested in, you'd use it in an `insert` statement. For example, you could create a button and create a process that fires when that button is pressed. It would then

```
insert into target_table (emp_id, salary, house_rent, ...)
  select emp_id, ... whatever you select in report's query
  from ...
```

---

However: data changes. What will you do when *something* - that is used to calculate those values - is changed? Will you delete those rows and insert new ones? Update existing values? Add yet another row?

If you'd *update* existing values, consider using `merge` as it is capable of inserting rows (in `when not matched` clause, in your case) , as well as updating rows (in `when matched`). That would look like this:

```
merge into target_table t
  using (select emp_id, ... whatever you select in report's query
         from ...
        ) x
  on (t.emp_id = x.emp_id)
when matched then update set
  t.salary = x.salary,
  t.house_rent = x.house_rent, 
  ...
when not matched then insert (emp_id, salary, house_rent, ...)
  values (x.emp_id, x.salary, x.house_rent, ...);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will use merge statement instead as per your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the INSERT INTO SELECT statement - plenty of examples available on google

```
  INSERT INTO another_table (
    emp_id,
    col1,
    col2
  )
    SELECT emp_id,
           calculated_col1,
           calculated_col2
      FROM first_table
```